# Tuckey UrlRewrite: ClassNotFoundException after changing urlrewrite.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter, urlrewriter

I'd like to be able to change the rules in urlrewrite.xml without restarting the server.

I am running Tomcat 7. In web.xml I have...

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
      <param-value>120</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
      <param-value>INFO</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
```

When I change the value of a `<to>` element in urlrewrite.xml, trying to execute that rule causes an exception.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jsp.s1.content.about_002dus_jsp    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   au.com.pawsforlife.vizsla.controller.UserFilter.doFilter(UserFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Does anyone know why this happens, or at least how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: A part in tomcat keeps the reference to compiled JSP's but clears the compiler output directory. It's most likely, that the change you did to `urlrewrite.xml` caused this behavior. Check out, whether https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes (adjusting context.xml, in particular reloadable) can help you.

Comment: Can you add your urlrewrite.xml as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is not the proper way to modify the rules dynamically.
Check the [Extending UrlRewriteFilter](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/guide.html#extending) section in the manual.

Instead of `rule` tag, you should use `class-rule`. You specify a class, that will dynamically load the rules from a resource.

They have an example of a [simple rule](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/java/org/tuckey/web/filters/urlrewrite/sample/SampleRewriteRule.java).

So basically you can't simply modify the XML file, you have to load the rules runtime, this way you can load any rules before the rewriting.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar exception in the past but I don't remember the details. That's why I am sharing my urlrewrite.xml and web.xml examples from a simple project. I hope it helps.
urlrewrite.xml:

```
  1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  2 <!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
  3         "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
  4
  5 <!--
  6
  7     Configuration file for UrlRewriteFilter
  8     http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/
  9
 10 -->
 11 <urlrewrite>
 12
 13     <rule>
 14         <from>^/OA_HTML/(.*)$</from>
 15         <to type="redirect">/tuckeyUrl/$1</to>
 16     </rule>
 17
78 </urlrewrite>
```

web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  2
  3 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  4      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  5      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
  6      version="2.4">
  7
  8 <filter>
  9     <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
 10     <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
 11 </filter>
 12 <filter-mapping>
 13     <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
 14     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 15     <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
 16     <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
 17 </filter-mapping>
 39 </web-app>
```

I also remember I had another exception. I fixed with removing the extra line before the first line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

from my web.xml.